# save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: hibernate

**Exception:** object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Child

**How to reproduce issue**:
1. Hibernate is load the entity "Parent". The property "child" is null
2. The "Parent" is rendered on the screen and after that the "child" property is auto instantiated. So I have the following graph:

```
Parent.child != null
Parent.child.childId = null
Parent.child.childKey = ""
Parent.child.childName = ""
```

**Question**: How I could to force the Hibernate to ignore updating or inserting Child entity WHEN childId = null? 
If childId != null I would like just create relation.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.test.Parent"
    entity-name="ParentObject" table="parent"
    dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="true" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="rowId" type="long">
      <column name="RowID" />
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <version name="versionSequence" type="integer"
      unsaved-value="null" generated="never" insert="false">
      <column name="VersionSequence" />
    </version>
    <many-to-one name="child" entity-name="Child" fetch="select"
      optimistic-lock="true" embed-xml="false" update="true" insert="false">
      <column name="ChildID" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="dateCreated" type="timestamp">
      <column name="DateCreated" length="0" />
    </property>
    <property name="dateUpdated" type="timestamp" update="false">
      <column name="DateUpdated" length="0" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.Child"
    entity-name="Child" table="Child" dynamic-insert="false"
    dynamic-update="true" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="childId" type="long" >
      <column name="ChildID" />
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <version name="versionSequence" type="integer" insert="false"
      generated="never" >
      <column name="VersionSequence" />
    </version>
    <property name="childKey" type="string" >
      <column name="ChildKey" length="20" />
    </property>
    <property name="childName" type="string" >
      <column name="ChildName" length="30" />
    </property>
    <property name="childNumber" type="string" >
      <column name="ChildNumber" />
    </property>
    <property name="dateCreated" type="timestamp">
      <column name="DateCreated" />
    </property>
    <property name="dateUpdated" type="timestamp" update="false">
      <column name="DateUpdated" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, your presentation layer adds an unnecessary child to the `Parent` object being displayed, and you want Hibernate to ignore it.

If so, it looks like a responsibility of the presentation layer to get rid of that child. So, it would be better to "sanitize" the `Parent` by removing that child inside a presentation layer before passing it back to Hibernate.

Comment: You are right. The Spring auto instantiate child object and if possible i would preserve this feature. So i finding a way how to teach the hibernate to ignore these kind of objects.

Comment: @eugenn: Once again: it's not a responsibility of Hibernate. If you pass incorrect model to the persistence layer, persistence layer would persist it incorrectly. Therefore you should remove these incorrect childs inside a controller.

Answer (score 5):

Use 'cascade' settings. Don't know how to do that with xml, but I'm sure you'll find it in the reference

Comment: <many-to-one name="vendor" entity-name="Vendor" fetch="select"
      optimistic-lock="true" embed-xml="false" update="true" insert="false" cascade="none">
      <column name="VendorID" /> 
    </many-to-one> it's not work as i expect. the hibernate throw TransientObjectException:

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your question. I agree with axtavt. Hibernate is the wrong place to do that. If you must, you might consider Interceptors, although I'm not sure they will work for this.